# Extending the Spring Security Login Process

Tags: spring, spring-security

Currently I have a custom form login page in Spring Security 3 that sends its form data to the correct authentication url.

However now I need to extend the process to support security questions after logging in but before hitting the rest of the site.

I have a few options from reading the documentation, but I'm confused as to the correct option to choose.

**Option 1:** Keep the current login system and set a special role that only lets the user access the security questions page. If they pass through the security questions process successfully, add their correct roles into the security context.

**Option 2:** Subclass AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter and do security questions as a part of the login process. This seems more spring-like but I'm stuck on how to support the multiple pages for the questions with breaking the rest of the authentication framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Option 1. @craftsman's answer doesn't fit since the questions are specific per user. Its actually worked out really well.

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach:

1. When a user submits her username/password, save them into her session.
2. Redirect her to your questions.
3. When she is finished answering your questions, see if you want to let her login.
   3.1. If yes, POST her saved credentials so that they could be caught and processed by Spring Security filter chain.
   3.2. If no, take her back to the login page. (Or whatever you want to do in this case.)

Comment: The issue with this approach is that I would have to check the user's password twice since a user shouldn't see their security question until after they have entered the password correctly.